# PDF image problem with position

Tags: graphics

I have difficulties to include more than 1 pdf image in my latex file. My code is as follow :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXX}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}

content 

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{\xxx\fig1.pdf}
\caption{}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

text

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{\xxx\fig2.pdf}
\caption{}\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

text

…

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `fig1.pdf` is shown, but `fig2.pdf` is shown at the end of my document on the last page, and not after the text that comes after `fig1.pdf`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `figure`s are floating this way, i.e. LaTeX puts it to a position where it 'thinks' it is best. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat for example to get possible solutions. And this is one of the most asked questions here ;-)

Comment: Try replacing `[hp]` with `[!htb]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I had a look, I have added right after `\begin{document}` `\setcounter{totalnumber}{8}`, I have try to change `\begin{figure}[hp]` into `\begin{figure}[h!]`… but it still does not show the image where it is supposed to be

Comment: I solved it ! I need to add `\usepackage{float}`and then write `\begin{figure}[H]`

Answer (score 0):

You give the options `[hp]`, which means *"put the figure **h**ere; if it doesn't fit on the page, put it on a separate **p**age"*. And this is what LaTeX does.

Removing the `p` option doesn't help, since the second figure still doesn't fit. If LaTeX took the `[h]` option literally, you would have a large empty space between the second text and the second figure. LaTeX doesn't like this and will automatically modify `[h]` to `[ht]`.

You have (at least) three options.

- Set the options to `[htbp]` or something similar. This way the figures will be as close as possible to the place where they have been defined. This is the intended usage of floats (`figure`s and `table`s).
- Load the package `float` und use the option `[H]`. This will place the figure where you have defined it, at the price of empty space if there is not enough room on the current page.
- Load the package `caption`, remove `\begin{figure}\centering ...\caption{...}\label{...}\end{figure}` and use `\begin{center}...\captionof{figure}{...}\label{...}\end{center}` instead. This will also place the figure where you have defined it, again at the price of empty space if there is not enough room on the current page.

See e.g. [WikiBooks: LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) for more information.

Below you find sample code for the second and third variant. The output is the same in both cases. Note the white space at the end of the first page, which may be considerably larger if there is less text to fill the gap.

[image]
[image]

Code for the `float` package and the `[H]` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Before figures.
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Between figures.
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{example-image-b}
\caption{B}\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

After figures.
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Code for the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Before figures.
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{A}\label{fig1}
\end{center}

Between figures.
\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{B}\label{fig2}
\end{center}

After figures.
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any new package, you can use `\FloatBarrier`, ... which insert the figure no later than the instruction, of course, as mentionned above, at the price of empty space if it does not fit. It is probably worth trying before anything else, if it fails then you can use the other solutions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXX}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[75]

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{fig1.pdf}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

After figure 1.
\lipsum[66]

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=65mm, height=65mm]{fig2.pdf}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]